# how to extract a part of string using regex

Tags: java, regex

Am trying to extract last three strings i.e. 05,06,07. However my regex is working the other way around which is extracting the first three strings. Can someone please help me rectify my mistake in the code.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((?:[^,]+,){2}(?:[^,]+)).+$");
String line = "CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2,1,11.65,42,42,42,42,04,05,06,07";
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
String result;
if (m.matches()) {
    result = m.group(1);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**My current output:**

```
CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2
```

**Expected output:**

```
05,06,07
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may fix it as

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,]*(?:,[^,]*){2}$");
String line = "CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2,1,11.65,42,42,42,42,04,05,06,07";
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
String result = "";
if (m.find()) {
    result = m.group(0);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wiEy6z)

The regex is

```
[^,]*(?:,[^,]*){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB3l48/1).

**Pattern details**

- `[^,]*` - 0+ chars other than `,`
- `(?:,[^,]*){2}` - 2 repetitions of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[^,]*` - 0+ chars other than `,`
- `$` - end of string.

Note that you should use `Matcher#find()` with this regex to find a *partial* match.